# intermittent logging of header in log4j2

Tags: logging, header, log4j2, pattern-layout

what is the possible error or issue in log4j2 in regards to logging the headers? below are the default configs of log4j2. is there any property that needs to be change to output the headers in log4j2
%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %m%n

we tried to change some parameters in property file pattern

Comment: "below are the default configs of log4j2": you didn't add any configuration file to your question.